# Dynamic column names and value

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

Below are the test data in my table.

```
col_names                             col_1       col_2         col_3

{col_names, col_1, col_2, col_3}      ABCD        XYZ           PQR
{col_names, col_1, col_2, col_3}      TYTY        UIO           ERT
```

Here, first column is name of the column in array. Here number of column will change depending on the first column.

I want to fetching the data through cursor and forming the string. Below is my logic. Here info_sql fetch above table data.

```
OPEN info_sql_curs FOR EXECUTE info_sql;
LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM info_sql_curs INTO info_sql_rec;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    -- First time - we need to fetch the column details..
    IF first_time THEN
        column_names := info_sql_rec.col_names;
        first_time := false;
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 2 .. array_upper(column_names,1)
    LOOP
        info_str := info_str || column_names[i] || ' = ' || 'info_sql_rec.' || column_names[i] || E'\n';
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
CLOSE info_sql_curs;
```

I want to form "info_sql_rec.col_1" and other column names. We can not hard code it because column names may change. I want to fetch details of "info_sql_rec.col_1", how to fetch value after forming string ?

Above method is correct ? Let me know idea if that incorrect ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show a complete function definition including the desired return type. And always your version of Postgres.